# How to extract value from json contained in a variable using jq in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jq

I am writing a bash script which has a json value stored in a variable now i want to extract the values in that json using Jq. The code used is.

```
json_val={"code":"lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg","redirect_to":"http://example.com/client-redirect-uri?code=lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg"}
  code_val= echo"$json_val" | jq '.code'
```

This throws an error of no such file or direcotry.

If i change this to

```
json_val={"code":"lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg","redirect_to":"http://example.com/client-redirect-uri?code=lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg"}
  code_val=echo" $json_val " | jq '.code'
```

This does not throws any error but the value in code_val is null.

If try to do it manually `echo {"code":"lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg","redirect_to":"http://example.com/client-redirect-uri?code=lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg"} | jq '.code'` it throws parse numeric letter error.

how can i do it in first case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use this:

```
json_val='{"code":"lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg","redirect_to":"http://example.com/client-redirect-uri?code=lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg"}'
code_val=$(jq -r '.code' <<< "$json_val")
echo "$code_val"
```

```
lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg
```

Note following changes:

- Wrap complete json string in single quotes
- use of `$(...)` for command substitution
- Use of `<<<` (here-string) to avoid a sub-shell creation

PS: If you're getting `json` text from a curl command and want to store multiple fields in shell variables then use:

```
read -r code_val redirect_to < <(curl ... | jq -r '.code + "\t" + .redirect_to')
```

Where `...` is your curl command.

Comment: in this you have put the json response in ''(single quotes) which makes changes it to literal string. I cannot do this coz i am getting the json_val as a curl response after i run the curl command in earlier line and  i save the response in that variable. Or please suggest a way to convert the data in variable to string and then pass to jq.

Comment: yeah but there are multiple fields which i need to extract and save in two different variable from the same curl response. Can you suggest a way to extract two values and save in two diff variable from the curl json response. That would do my work.

Comment: it does work but also throws errors of echoset not defined 

read -r code_val redirect_to < <(curl http://5dba6fe9eddc81001495f72c.mockapi.io/tyk_test/rate_    poc | jq -r '.rate + "\t" + .individual')
 
 
  echo"$code_val"
  echo"$redirect_to"

Comment: Run curl with my suggested ka command on shell and see if that runs fine

Answer (score 0):

If try to do it manually:

```
$ echo {"code":"lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg","redirect_to":"http://example.com/client-redirect-uri?code=lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg"} | jq '.code'
```

...it throws parse numeric letter error.

seems like you did not escape the string of the `echo` command. in your case, escaping with a singe-quote (apostrophe `'`) will do - same as you  did with  the `jq` json-path argument (`'.code'`)

```
$ echo '{"code":"lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg","redirect_to":"http://example.com/client-redirect-uri?code=lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg"}' | jq '.code'
"lyz1To6ZTWClDHSiaeXyxg"
```