# How to append a json variable to another?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I want to avoid using JSON files and use variables but it doesn't work

```
element='{"x": "zero"}'
example='{
    "a": "one",
    "b": "two",
    "c": "three",
}'

jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' element.json example.json
```

If the contents of the JSON files are exactly as what's inside the single quotes of the vars it works as expected. But I also want the element to be the first one (with `*` it doesn't go first, with `+=`, it makes another object)

If I replace the filenames with `$element` and `$example`, it fails (expecting a file)

I tried like this:

```
jq --argjson el "$element" --argjson ex "$example" '$el += $ex'
```

but it says `jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson`. I don't get it. The vars seem to be correct JSON.

I just want this output, "x" first, using variables not files:

```
{
    "x": "zero",
    "a": "one",
    "b": "two",
    "c": "three",
}
```

Comment: see the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59551619/how-to-extract-value-from-json-contained-in-a-variable-using-jq-in-bash

Comment: The last key-value pair in a JSON object cannot end with a comma.

Comment: That answer uses the `<<<` for one variable, to extract an attribute value which is not what I need. The second part with read uses that extracted value and also doesn't seem to address my problem. I'm even more confused  @rabbit

Comment: Also, don't use `+=`, just `+`

Comment: _Also_, when you're not feeding files to `jq`, it will "block" reading stdin unless you use the `--null-input` (`-n`) option.

Comment: SUCCESS!!  Removing the comma and `jq -n --argjson el "$element" --argjson ex "$example" '$el + $ex'` did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using the comment suggestions like this

```
element='{"x":"zero"}'
example='{
    "a":"one",
    "b":"two",
    "c":"three"
}'
jq -n --argjson el "$element" --argjson ex "$example" '$el + $ex'
```